# forwarding Web App Authentication to API Service

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an application that is broken down into a Web App (Asp .net MVC) that talks to an API Service both written in C# .net core 2.2.  I have the web app using the built in AZure AD authentication.  This works fine, as it prompts the user for their Azure domain id and password and only lets in the specific users.

I did the same for the API service. All the startup.cs code was set appropriately.

I would like to use the authentication from the web app and forward to the api service but can't figure out a way to do that or even access it.

I've tried added different authentication schemes (azureadbearer and jwtbearer), but those just made the web app not work, never prompted for authentication

In the web app this uses the Azure AD and requires users to be authenticated:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddAzureAD(options =>
  {
       Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
  });
```

in the API Service, I have

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
      .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

but I can't figure out how/what the web app should call to authorize or get a token for the api service.  If I add the [Authorize] attribute for the api controller, I will get an unauthorized error calling it from the web app.

I would like to be able to use or get a token that was created when the user authorizes to the web app and forward that on to the api service, but didn't see anything in the headers that resembled a jwt token.

I also tried creating a jwt token in the web app and set the Authorization header (bearer token) and sent to the api service, and changed the api service to use jwtbearer instead, but I would still get an unauthorized.

I've spent days trying to find examples and get this working with no luck, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...would love to be able to use the built AzureAD middleware and not have to write any code to handle this if possible.

This is what I tried in the api service but didn't validate the token I sent:
            s

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
  {
      cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
      cfg.SaveToken = true;
      cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
      {
          ValidIssuer = Configuration["ServiceAd:Issuer"],
          ValidAudience = Configuration["ServiceAd:Audience"],
          IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ServiceAd:ClientSecret"]))
      };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use **OAuth2.0 on-behalf-of flow**. As per your requirement, you want to authenticate the user in web app and create a token for web api and call web api from Web app controller.

First create 2 service principals, one is for web app and second is for web api. Then go to web app service principal --> permission section and add web api (service principal) and grant the permission.

After creating service principals, you need to use OAuth 2.0  On-behalf-of flow in web app controller. 
Once you run the web app, you have to authenticate user with username and password, after authenticating the user you can get the access_token by using HttpContext in your controller action method, then use On-behalf-of flow flow to get the another token for web api and make a call to web api to access the resource.

You can check the below documentation for on-behalf-of flow:
[OAuth2.0 On-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)

In web app--> HomeController.cs --> Index() method get the current token (first time when you login you get the access token), use that token to create another token for web api.

Below is the code for on-behalf-of flow:

```
 private async Task<string> GetOnBehalfToken()
    {
        // Get User Assertion
        var authenticateInfo = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync("Bearer");
        string incomingToken = authenticateInfo.Properties.Items[".Token.access_token"];
        UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(incomingClientToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");

        string token = string.Empty;
        string authString = string.Format(this.azureAd.AadInstance, this.azureAd.TenantId);
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);

        // config for oauth client credentials
        // Use Web app client id and secret key
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(this.azureAd.ClientId, this.azureAd.AppKey);

        // App ID uri of web api service principal
        var resource = "https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/45854ee0-608a-4dff-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx";

        AuthenticationResult result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

Once you get the token for web api, add it into Authorization header of http client and make a call to api.

If you only want to authenticate your web api with Azure AD. Use the below code in startup and see if it works for you:

```
public static void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
           new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
           {
               Tenant = Configuration["AzureAD.TenantId"],
               TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
               {
                   ValidateIssuer = true,
                   ValidIssuer = Configuration["AzureAD.Issuer"],
                   ValidAudience = Configuration["AzureAD.Audience"],
                   ValidateLifetime = true
               }
           });

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["AzureAD.Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["AzureAD.Audience"],
                    ValidateLifetime = true
                }
            });
    }
```

Also verify that Issuer({tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com) and Audience(App Id uri of service principal) values, those should be correct.

I hope this solve your issue.

Comment: I'm not quite following your sample...does this go in the web app or api?  I've looked at that article before and it's not really what I want.  I want to use the Azure AD that we have to authenticate the users in the web app.  This currently works fine, but I would also like to use that autnentication to secure/access the api service.  The first line of code (when run in the web app) crashes with no auth handler is configured for Bearer

Comment: You want to access web api from your web app. If that is the case, the above code will be in web app.
You are able to authenticate a user in web app and need a token to call web api. In that case, the on-behalf-of flow will be used.
If you want to independently authenticate your api, I would suggest to create a web api project with default Api template and choose Authentication as "Work or School accounts" and check the startup.cs file with your api--> startup.cs file.

Comment: My web app and api are set up with authentication as "Work or School accounts", the web app authorizes the logged in user properly, but I can't figure out where/what kind of token that is generated from that, and your code sample does not find anything (no bearer token).  It seems like this should be pretty straight forward, but I've been banging my head for weeks now trying to be able to secure the api side, can't even get it to authorize using the jwtbearer scheme...just either get a no default scheme found or just an unauthorized error, but no way to debug to see what is happening.

Comment: modified my answer, added code snippet, you can use that code in startup.cs of web api.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't help, I think that is also from an older .net version? Not sure what /where that ConfigureAuthentication method is called?  If you create a web app, and set the wizard authentication to work or school, and choose your ad domain, it will set up the web app properly and require authentication.  Now do the same for a new web api and choose the same AD for that projects authentication.  How do you create a token for the API from the web app, preferably using the authentication from the web app?